# How to automatically implement gravity when key is released? How to allow for continuous jumping?

Tags: pygame, python-3.5

In my code when the player's avatar jumps to a certain point gravity brings it back down. However this only works when the up and space buttons are held until the certain point is reached. In the case the button is released I would like to send the duck back down with gravity using this piece of code:

```
player.rect.move_ip(0, (player.speed) * -player.y_direction)
```

I don't know how to make the check to see if it is released and then automatically implement it.

Also another problem I would like help with is when the duck lands back on the floor the buttons must be released then retapped. I would like to update the code so as long as the buttons are pressed the avatar will jump fall back to the ground and then it will automatically go back to jumping with the condition the space and up buttons are held down.

Here is the full code:
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        """The player controlled Duck"""

```
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Player, self).__init__(x, y, width, height)

        # How many pixels the Player duck should move on a given frame.
        self.y_change = 0
        # How many pixels the spaceship should move each frame a key is pressed.
        self.y_dist = 150
        self.x_change = 0
        # How many pixels the spaceship should move each frame a key is pressed.
        self.x_dist = 30
        self.x_direction = 1
        # Positive = down, negative = up
        self.y_direction = -1
        # Current speed.
        self.speed = 13

duck = pygame.image.load('walkingduck.png')
player = Player(0, (window_height)-125, 120, 160) #Making player object(duck)

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
move = False

while True:  # the main game loop
    if move: #Jumping process
        key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP] or key_pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if player.rect.y<=320:
                move=False
            else:
                player.rect.move_ip(0, player.speed * player.y_direction)
    if move==False and player.rect.y<=(window_height)-115:
        player.rect.move_ip(0, (player.speed) * -player.y_direction)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Closes game
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            move=True

            #Adds images and text
    screen.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: So the duck should fly upwards if the key is pressed, otherwise downwards?

Comment: It already does that. However upon release the duck stays in the air unless  it flies up to a certain point (Key is held down) when it comes down. So I want to make it so anytime key is released then send it back down towards to the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in this way: If the player is flying set the `y_change` to a negative number, otherwise add the GRAVITY value to it so that it accelerates downwards. Then move the rect and clamp it. (I'd actually put the movement code into the `update` method of the `Player` class.)

```
import sys
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((230, 200, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.y_change = 0


pygame.init()
GRAVITY = .9
window_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, window_height))
player = Player(200, 50, 40, 30)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group(player)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
move = False
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            move = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            move = False

    if move:  # Fly upwards.
        player.y_change = -9
    else:  # Add the gravity to the y-velocity.
        player.y_change += GRAVITY
    player.rect.move_ip(0, player.y_change)
    # Clamp the rect.y value to the range 50 to 450-rect.h.
    # You could also use rect.clamp_ip((0, 50, 800, 450)).
    if player.rect.y < 50:
        player.rect.y = 50
        player.y_change = 0
    elif player.rect.bottom >= window_height-150:
        player.rect.bottom = window_height-150
        player.y_change = 0

    screen.fill((30, 100, 140))
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Here's the variant with the `update` method and `rect.clamp_ip`.

```
import sys
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((230, 200, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.y_change = 0
        self.flying = False

    def update(self):
        if self.flying:
            self.y_change = -9
        self.y_change += GRAVITY
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.y_change)
        self.rect.clamp_ip((0, 50, 800, 450))
        if self.rect.y <= 50:
            self.y_change = 1


pygame.init()
GRAVITY = .5
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player(200, 50, 40, 30)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group(player)
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.flying = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player.flying = False

    all_sprites_list.update()
    screen.fill((30, 100, 140))
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

**Edit:** Here's the version with continuous jumping instead of a smooth upwards movement.

```
import sys
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((230, 200, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.y_change = 0
        self.flying = False

    def update(self):
        if self.flying:
            # If the y_change is getting too big,
            # reset it to -13 to fly upwards again.
            if self.y_change > 5:
                self.y_change = -13
        # Accelerate downwards each frame.
        self.y_change += GRAVITY
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.y_change)
        self.rect.clamp_ip((0, 50, 800, 450))
        if self.rect.y <= 50:
            self.y_change = 1


pygame.init()
GRAVITY = .9
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player(200, 50, 40, 30)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group(player)
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.flying = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            player.flying = False

    all_sprites_list.update()
    screen.fill((30, 100, 140))
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This perfectly helped me out with all my jumping problems.

Comment: Do you know how to make it so upon holding the button down it can't stay in the air but gravity pulls it down?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Should the player just jump one time when the button is pressed and not fly upwards constantly?

Comment: It should not fly upwards constantly. It should come down after jumping and then be able to go back up if the button is still held down.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want it to look like a flying or flapping bird. While the key is held, it should ascend, then descend a bit, ascend again and so on, correct?

Comment: I've added another version, with this continuous jumping behaviour. I hope that's what you wanted.